# Mute jQuery Migrate in Ruby on Rails test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-migrate

Our rails project receives a lot of JQMIGRATE message when running tests, eg:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr(selected) may use property instead of attribute
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated
```

Obviously it would be good to fix them, but they seem to be due to other gems anyway.

I've seen reference to `jQuery.migrateMute = true`, but not sure where to include it, and more importantly, would like to mute in test environment but not development. What's the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Jquery-Migrate is a javascript library. So you can add `jQuery.migrateMute = true` in application.js before you start using deprecated method of jquery. Because it's just js, so I think you can comment in it while developing and comment out it while testing :)